# WebRequest A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server

Tags: c#, rest, webrequest, ssis-2016

using a Webrequest within a script task to consume a Rest Service

I get the following error

> A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the
>   server

I'm calling the rest service within a For Each Loop container.
It works the first time but not any subsequent executions.

searching stack overflow I've come across the following settings tha have helped others but not me

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 5000;
```

I'm thinking it's because the KeepAlive property is set to true but I can't see a way to change it and [it isn't a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) that can be changed

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can cast

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://www.server.com/api/stuff") as HttpWebRequest;

req.KeepAlive = false;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

or override

```
internal class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        req.KeepAlive = false;

        return req;
    }
}
```

your `WebRequest` to access further properties that are hidden or abstracted!